# SSRS - "View Report" button still shows English in French environment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have developed a SSRS report, executed in English environment using website.  Works fine. User change language to French using a link on site. Runs report. In report viewer, language is retrieved from current culture settings which is now French.

When report runs, everything appears in French but "View Report" button on Parameter selection criteria panel, appears in English which is suppose to be in French as well. Have no idea from where this English text coming and not translated in French? Is there any hidden property or environment that also needs to be change? please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser language setting is set to English Reporting Services will use that language for:

- Report Manager
- Report Viewer toolbar
- My Reports folder name
- Localized elements of the report server folder hierarchy and report
  server content types, when the Report Server Web service is accessed
  through a browser window.

View report button caption is determined by client browser settings.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In development server, report text is in French if we switch language from UI, but only on this server, it always shows in English.

Comment: The data and report items language is determined by the Locale property you set in the server or in the particular item property. ReportViewer controls language like View Report button is determined by the browser that requests the report. [How to check the language your browser is sending to report server](http://mybrowserinfo.com/)